# More professional way of saying Correcting a Mistake

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, phrase-usage

I need to rewrite "correct a mistake" into something more professional. I can think of "amending a mistake" or rectifying it, but none seems to sound well (I want to put emphasis on a word that's accepted in English literature). THe idea is to say: Correct a mistake made in the system (say because of spelling error).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108999/discussion-on-question-by-user387655-more-professional-way-of-saying-correcting).

Answer (score 1):

There’s nothing unprofessional about “correcting a mistake.”

Answer (score 0):

One typically corrects mistakes in publications by issuing **errata** (s. **erratum**). From Lexico:

> **[erratum](https://www.lexico.com/definition/erratum)**: An error in printing or writing.
>
> *Example sentence*: ‘The publisher has inserted an *erratum* slip noting three errors in dates and explaining that a contrite Hoban ‘writes at all hours of the day and night, sometimes when a little the worse for wear’.’
>
> **[errata](https://www.lexico.com/definition/erratum)**: A list of corrected errors appended to a book or published in a subsequent issue of a journal.
>
> *Example sentence*: 'Periodicals would use *errata* sections to correct some of the errors, and letters to the editor could be used to debate a previous article's contentions and possibly set the record straight.’

A less common term is **corrigendum** (pl. **corrigenda**). From Lexico:

> **[corrigendum](https://www.lexico.com/definition/corrigendum)**: A thing to be corrected, typically an error in a printed book.
>
> *Example sentence*: ‘the 1980-84 cumulation contains *corrigenda* which are not included in the annual volumes’

If you're interested in a less formal context, you could use the simple word **correction**.

> Example sentence: '**Correction**: Please replace *dictionray* with *dictionary*.'

Totally professional.

Answer (score -1):

A professional way to say it would be to *Remedy* a mistake. That is to make them right.
It has the charm of admitting that they were wrong and needed fixing without the clinical feel of the surgeon's hand actually pulling it together.

```
 The new volume will have Remedied several mistakes.
```